# JS: Using data-attribute from HTML as a call for a variable in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I think I am looking for the wrong things.

What I basically have is this construction

```
<a data-id="bgU"></a>
```

In my JS I have a variable inside PIXI.js called bgU which has my texture loaded into it.

```
var bgU = new PIXI.Sprite(texture01);
```

To call this var from a click on the link I would like to have something that can be used like this and that is exactly where I am currently stuck not getting any further.

```
elN = $(this).attr("data-id");
container.addChild(elN);
```

So my question is: How do I actually access the data-id as such that I can use it as a direct pointer?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you using pure javascript or jquery? update the tags accordingly.

Comment: @dekel I am using jQuery. Will do :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend putting all of these variables into an object like this:

```
var sprites = {};
sprites.bgU = new PIXI.Sprite(texture01);
```

Then you can get the property:

```
container.addChild(sprites[elN]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. It works great and is quiet simple as well! Learned another thing again.